# I'm looking for a word meaning "hard to pronounce"

Tags: single-word-requests

I heard it from a radio station and just don't know how to spell it out.
It sounds something like "malfolk" and means words that don't know how to pronounce, *szmczyk*, for example.

Does anyone know the word?

Comment: Szmczyk is easy to pronounce for a Pole: "shm-chick".

Comment: Shouldn't that be "szymczyk"? :)

Comment: I don't get what's so hard about names like that.  Like the coach from Duke.  It's obviously pronounced crazy-zoo-ski

Comment: @Spook No, "Szmczyk" is a perfectly cromulent Polish name pronounced /ʂmt͡ʂɨk/. (the m is not syllabic)

Comment: @MarkBeadles, Actually, I am Pole and though I know a few Szymczyk's, I know no Szmczyk. Though there seem to be a few "Szmczyk"s on the Internet, I'd rather vote on misspelling rather than on existence of such surname. Can you provide word-base for such surname?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I believe the word you are looking for is *mouthful*.

[Dictionary.com defines mouthful as](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mouthful)  (amongst other meanings) :

> A long word or group of words, especially one that is hard to pronounce.

It is commonly used in English - e.g., "that was a real mouthful."

Comment: I really feel "mouthful" more refers to, oh, "big, technical, compound" sort of words, like nitrosilicontransacidfat.  Easy to pronounce, but a "mouthful".  Words like Blois (the town), say, are basically impossible to pronounce - I wouldn't really use "mouthful" there.

Comment: @JoeBlow Perhaps it is more of a UK/Commonwealth usage.  When one mispronounces any word, it is common to finish by saying "well that was a real mouthful" with intended embarrassment.  But you are right that it is most often associated with big, technical words.  Regardless, I think *mouthful* best matches the OPs request that is sounds like *malfolk*.

Comment: It's a pity that malfolk isn't a real word. It sounds as if it ought to be a word for something.

Comment: It's also a pity that the word for this is so easy to pronounce. It would be great if there were an autological word for it. :)

Answer (score 21):

A word difficult to pronounce is **"a jawbreaker"**

> - jawbreaker - "a word that is difficult to pronounce" - [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jawbreaker)

**"a tongue-twister"** usually refers to a word or sequence of words difficult to pronounce.

> - tongue-twister - "a word or sequence of words difficult to pronounce, especially rapidly, because of alliteration or a slight variation of consonant sounds" - [**DC**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tongue-twister)

examples of jawbreakers (for some people)

- "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
- "diaphragmatic"
- "fait accompli"
- "dowager"

examples of tongue-twisters:

- "where she sits she shines, and where she shines she sits."
- "can you can a can as a canner can can a can?"
- "I wish I were what I was when I wished I were what I am.

Comment: Yes, jawbreaker: a tongue twister (BrE)

Comment: +1, though I usually associate jawbreaker with [this](http://wholesale.albaneseconfectionery.com/all-distributed-items/mother-of-all-jawbreakers-4-400273/). Took me a week to finish my first jawbreaker...

Answer (score 7):

How about [**Crackjaw**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crackjaw):

> crackjaw (ˈkrækˌdʒɔː)
>
> *adj*
>
> difficult to pronounce
>
> *n*
>
> a word or phrase that is difficult to pronounce

[Wikitonary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crackjaw) also gives some info;

> English
>
> Etymology
>
> crack +‎ jaw
>
> Adjective
>
> crackjaw ‎(not comparable)
>
> Difficult or unpleasant to pronounce.
>
> a crackjaw language
>
> a crackjaw name

Comment: *supercalifragilisticexpialidocious* is a mouthful, but I don't have any trouble pronouncing it. Plus one for offing a word that the definition for is “hard to pronounce”.

Comment: @Mazura I think you commented on the wrong answer? This answer is about "crackjaw", not "mouthful" ([here](/a/366674/90081)).

Comment: @Constant'sErik - Nope. It's a jab at both of the answers that are above this one for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend "**unenunciable**"; literally, a word which cannot be enunciated (spoken aloud). To [enunciate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enunciate) means

> Say or pronounce clearly

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your answer was automatically flagged as low-quality for its length and content. Can you include some examples where the word *unenunciable* is used to mean what the OP wants?